# Parse/Validate CSR code

Tags: php, validation, csr

I'm using trustico.com reseller api in order to process ssl certificates. But interestingly I couldn't find any tool for parse CSR code for getting approver email list. There is only one tool in tructico api that requires domain name for getting list.

My question is there any tool for parsing CSR code in PHP in order to get associated domain name? or does trustico api give me a chance to get it?

Thanks in advance

edit:  (I coulnt write this as an aswer, so I edit my question)

I make another search and I find this online csr validation tool :

https://secure.comodo.net/utilities/decodeCSR.html

it also gives you an api which you can make queries locally. documentation is here :

https://secure.comodo.net/api/pdf/DecodeCSR%20v1.06.pdf

I wrote it for myself in order to get domain. if csr code is given is correct code returns full domain, if it's not code returns "1".  I hope it helps someone needs :

```
function ssl_getCN($csr) {
    $api_url = "http://secure.comodo.net/products/!DecodeCSR";

    $fields = array('csr' =>$csr,
            'showCN'=>'Y',
            'showErrorCodes'=>'N',
            'showErrorMessages'=>'N',
            'showFieldNames'=>'N',
            'showEmptyFields'=>'N',
            'showEmptyFields'=>'N',
            'showAddress'=>'N',
            'showPublicKey'=>'N',
            'showKeySize'=>'N',
            'showSANDNSNames'=>'N',
            'showCS'=>'N'
            );

    // URL Encode Values
    $query_string = http_build_query($fields);


    // Initiate CURL POST call
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);    
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query_string);            
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;

}
```